# java : I need to display the integers as String value without adding those?

Tags: java

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 1;
        int c = 0;
        int d = 2;
        int e = 0;
        String result;
    }
}
```

Here i want to have the result value to be as   01020

I tried this way

```
int a = 0;
        int b = 1;
        int c = 0;
        int d = 2;
        int e = 0;


         String aString = Integer.toString(a);
         String bString = Integer.toString(b);
         String cString = Integer.toString(c);
         String dString = Integer.toString(d);
         String eString = Integer.toString(e);

         String result = aString+bString+cString+dString+eString;
```

Please tell me how can i implement the result to have it print as 01020

Thanks you very much

Comment: did you try something already???

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
String result = String.format("%d%d%d%d%d", a, b, c, d, e);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
System.out.println("" + a + b + c + d + e);
```

The `"" + ...` forces the result type of String, so the values won't be added together (as long as you don't use parens).

Answer (score 1):

You can use String.valueOf(a) or java.lang.Integer's toString() method.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String result = String.valueOf(0) + String.valueOf(1) + String.valueOf(0) + String.valueOf(2) + String.valueOf(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test { 
 public static void main(String args[]) { 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int a = 0; 
    int b = 1; 
    int c = 0; 
    int d = 2; 
    int e = 0; 
    sb.append(String.valueOf(a));
    sb.append(String.valueOf(b));
    sb.append(String.valueOf(c));
    sb.append(String.valueOf(d));
    sb.append(String.valueOf(e));
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

}

Comment: The `String.valueOf(` and `.toString()` are redundant.

Answer (score 0):

The optimal solution is to take the numbers and multiply by the corresponding base 10 power so it only has to create one String object rather than one for each number and concatenate them together - which also creates a new String object per concatenation.

```
int a = 0;
int b = 1;
int c = 0;
int d = 2;
int e = 0;
String result = String.valueOf(a*1+b*10+c*100+d*1000+e*10000);
```